# Why does my SKSpriteNode slowly move to the upper right corner of the screen during repeated animation?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics

My spriteNode is slowly moving to the upper right corner of my SKScene. I noticed that changing the timing modes of the actions in my didMoveToView(..) can cause a change in direction. What is causing this behaviour, and how can I fix it?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   let spriteNode = self.childNodeWithName("character") as! SKSpriteNode

    spriteNode.zRotation = CGFloat((M_PI / 2) / 1.3)

    let rotation1 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat((-M_PI / 2)), duration: 1)
    rotation1.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

    let rotation2 = rotation1.reversedAction()
    rotation2.duration = 0.4
    rotation2.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.Linear

    let path = self.generatePath1()
    let movement1 = SKAction.followPath(path, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 1)
    movement1.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

    let movement2 = movement1.reversedAction()
    movement2.duration = 0.4
    movement1.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.Linear

    let rotations = SKAction.sequence([rotation1, rotation2])
    spriteNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotations))

    let movements = SKAction.sequence([movement1, movement2])
    spriteNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(movements)
}

func generatePath1() -> CGPathRef {
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(30, 50), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(30, 50), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(20, 40))

        return bezierPath.CGPath
    }
```

Comment: If you set the `followPath`'s `asOffset` parameter to false, the sprite won't drift over time. You will need to change the path to absolute instead of relative coordinates.